# Regex string replace in c#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have one string like

```
var input =  "data1, data2, 1233456,  \"\"\" test, data, here \"\"\", 08976, test data"
```

I want to replace `\"\"\" test, data, here \"\"\"` part of this string with  `test; data; here`

In simple words replace comma `','` with semincolon `';'` any string inside `\"\"\"` block only.

I am trying to do this with a Regular expression.

I am trying to use following regex - `\[\\\\\"](.+)[\\\\\"]`

Comment: Go ahead and add your abortive code attempts to your question.  It won't make the question more clear, but it may allow people to point out a small misconception you may have...and it also makes people much more likely to answer the question (odd, but true.)

Comment: As @Beska says ... people are more likely to help if they know you have tried. Posting your code shows that

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, if you want a non-regex solution to compare, you can do this with LINQ as well:

```
input= string.Join("\"\"\"", 
         input.Split(new []{"\"\"\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)
         .Select( (s,i) => i % 2 == 1 ? s.Replace (',', ';') : s)
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guy for help,

Your answers were useful.

Finally managed to do this with following code with help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584181/a-string-replace-function-with-support-of-custom-wildcards-and-escaping-these-wi?rq=1)

```
//My input string
var input  = Regex.Replace(input  , "[\\\"](.+)[\\\"]", ReplaceMethod);


//Method used to replace 
public static string ReplaceMethod(Match m)
    {
        string newValue = m.Value;
        return newValue.Replace("\"", "").Replace(",", ";");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this with regex for this string:
`data1, 1233456,  """ test, data, here """, 08976, test, """ second, data """, aso`

It is possible for:
`data1, 1233456,  < test, data, here >, 08976, test, < second, data >, aso`

but not "xxx"

pattern: `\"{3}.*\"{3}`
foreach regex matching this pattern string.replace(',', ';')

but i'm trying to make regex...

and I give up :/

Comment: Please check my answer, it's possible

Answer (score 0):

The following code is might satisfy the requirement...

> var output = Regex.Replace(input  ,
>   "(?<=\"\"\".+),(?=.+\"\"\")", ";");

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this with regex for this string:
`data1, 1233456, """ test, data, here """, 08976, test, """ second, data """, aso`

Comment: Can you confirm that the input is data1, data2, 1233456,  """ test, data, here """, 08976, test data (without the escape characters)?

Comment: When you run above Regex.Replace you should get...data1, data2, 1233456,  """ test; data; here """, 08976, test data (without the escape). Let me know if that is/isn's what you are looking for.

Comment: you can test here: http://fiddle.re/5mawn but even if you fix this it will be correct for data after """ and before begining of the next """